# Zero-Knowledge Proof of Subgraph Isomorphism

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I'm trying to find a Zero-Knowledge proof of subgraph isomorphism in the following scenario: Alice and Bob both know about graphs `G1` and `G2`. Alice knows about a subgraph of `G1` which is isomorphic to `G2`. How can Alice convince Bob that she knows of this subgraph existing without giving Bob any help with finding the subgraph.

I'm a bit confused on the entire concept of Zero-Knowledge proofs, so anything that could help me get started on this problem would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Does Alice also know an isomorphism from that subgraph to `G2`? $\;$

Comment: You can always just use a zero knowledge proof for NP, and reduce the problem to the NP instance (e.g., 3COL, HAM).